# Split Time range into multiple time periods based on interval in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I have a time-range and an interval, I need to split the time range into multiple time periods based on interval value.

For example, time range is 9:30 to 11:30 and the interval is 30, the output time periods should be in a list as datetime objects

**Output:**

```
[
2020-08-24 9:30 - 2020-08-24 10:00,
2020-08-24 10:00 - 2020-08-24 10:30 
2020-08-24 10:30 - 2020-08-24 11:00, 
2020-08-24 11:00 - 2020-08-24 11:30
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do arithmetic on `datetime` objects by adding `timedelta` objects.

You probably need to decide exactly what behaviour is required if the interval per period is not an exact divisor of the total, but this example would give a final short period in that case.

```
import datetime

tstart = datetime.datetime(2020,8,24,9,30)
tend = datetime.datetime(2020,8,24,11,30)
interval = datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)

periods = []

period_start = tstart
while period_start < tend:
    period_end = min(period_start + interval, tend)
    periods.append((period_start, period_end))
    period_start = period_end

print(periods)
```

This gives (with newlines inserted for readability):

```
[(datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 9, 30), datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 10, 0)),
 (datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 10, 30)),
 (datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 10, 30), datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 11, 0)),
 (datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 11, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 11, 30))]
```

For the string output format that you want, you could do something like this:

```
def format_time(dt):
    return dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

print(['{} - {}'.format(format_time(start), format_time(end))
       for start, end in periods])
```

to give:

```
['2020-08-24 09:30 - 2020-08-24 10:00',
 '2020-08-24 10:00 - 2020-08-24 10:30',
 '2020-08-24 10:30 - 2020-08-24 11:00',
 '2020-08-24 11:00 - 2020-08-24 11:30']
```

Comment: instead of doing `datetime.timedelta(0, 60) * 30` you can also do `datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)`

Answer (score 5):

Using [pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

```
import pandas as pd

bins = pd.date_range(start='2020-08-24 9:30', end='2020-08-24 11:30', freq='30min').astype(str)
res = [' - '.join(x) for x in zip(bins[: -1], bins[1: ])]

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['2020-08-24 09:30:00 - 2020-08-24 10:00:00',
 '2020-08-24 10:00:00 - 2020-08-24 10:30:00',
 '2020-08-24 10:30:00 - 2020-08-24 11:00:00',
 '2020-08-24 11:00:00 - 2020-08-24 11:30:00']
```